# How can I list a specific row or a number of rows?

Tags: smartsheet-api

I am following the REST API documentation for SmartSheet and understand how to make a GET call to retrieve all rows in a sheet. However I am trying to find a more efficient way than getting all rows because a) I know the row number I need and b) the sheets have a lot of rows and I really don't need to retrieve all this data just to end up discarding it. I need to do this on a lot of sheets with a lot of rows, so I'm trying to be computationally efficient.

I understand there is the concept of paging and page size in the API as well. So I thought maybe I could only page the number of rows I need (ex: first 8) and then just select the last one in the list. However paging doesn't seem to apply to rows, even though you can do so with columns.

Am I misunderstanding something or is it true that to get any row data, you have to pull all rows? I just need to get the row ID so I can then retrieve the data I need. It just doesn't sound right in row-based data that you have to pull all rows. Thanks in advance for any insight.

Answer (score 1):

And indeed, I was missing something :) You can include a parameter with the call as a comma-delimited list of row numbers (rowNumbers). Tested and it works like a charm. https://smartsheet-platform.github.io/api-docs/?shell#get-sheet

Comment: That same page also notes the rowIds query string which can be used in the same way. This is helpful if the rows you are looking for might move on the sheet. The rowIds are unique to the sheet and will stay with the rows until they are deleted from the sheet. Row numbers might update as the rows move around on the sheet from sorting or as rows get inserted in different places and the rows shift positions.

Comment: Thanks @daveskull81. In my case there will be a lot of sheets started from the same template so I won't know what row ID I need. So I'll use the row number just to retrieve the row ID, then get the cell data I need. It would be nice if you actually didn't need to make a call with the row ID and simply do it by row number. But that's one for the wishlist :)

Comment: Are you thinking about being able to do a GET Row request and use the row number instead of the Row Id? In that case since you would need to know the Sheet Id for a GET Row request you could just do a GET Sheet request and provide the row number to return back just the single row object like you are doing now.

Comment: Thanks again @daveskull81, you're absolutely right. That gives me exactly what I need.